# Spark Find the Occurrences of Matched Strings

Tags: apache-spark

how i can find the occurence of the matched string as per the below code snippet, i'm able to get the filtered strings as an output , but not the occurences

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

object WordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

 val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("wordCount")


 val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  // Load our input data.
 val input =  sc.textFile("file:///tmp/ganesh/*")

 val matched_pattern = input.filter(line => line.contains("Title"))

 // Split it up into words.
val words = matched_pattern.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))

// Transform into pairs and count.
 val counts = words.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey{case (x, y) => x + y}

 // Save the word count back out to a text file, causing evaluation.
 counts.saveAsTextFile("file:///tmp/sparkout")

  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe add some input and output. Do you just want count of the word "Title" in that case?

Comment: @thebluephantom - Yes, there would be multiple matching strings.

** Input File **

  updateBranding: $loginPage.view_onUpdateBranding } }"><!--  --> <div id="loginHeader" class="row text-title" role="heading" data-bind="text: str[&#39;WF_STR_HeaderDefault_Title&#39;]">Sign in</div> <div class="row text-body no-margin-top" data-bind="ifnot: svr.BD"> <div id="loginDescription" data-bind="

**Expected Output ***
Title, 2

Comment: Was the answer what you were looking for?

Comment: yes, when i ran the code with the sample dataset it works

but, when i run the same code with the production dataset i only get the result of the first matching string 

for example : filter_words.txt contains "Google  dropbox title" and i would get the count only for Google and not for the dropbox and title

Comment: You need to show the format of your data in the question. It is unclear to me what you are asking now. My stuff is based on a text file.

Comment: At ;least you have a better basis than originally I believe.

Comment: please find the data link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/17lynBtLffNi2AZCQ92dQR8JRTFUx-Voj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok will look tomorrow

Comment: This is the input file to process? The file of match words is?

Comment: So the issue is if you want wordX it is not found as it has format wordX= for example?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: @thebluephantom - i haven't tested the code yet, please give me some time, i shall let you know

Comment: Please note you can make the selection / regex to be what you want. That will affect the results. I just did some elementary stuff thinking what you may want based on the file example you shared.

Comment: Any time to have looked at?

Comment: Time found to look at?

Comment: Any time had yet?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example - with broadcast variable usage. stopWords is in fact include words.

```
val dfsFilename = "/FileStore/tables/7dxa9btd1477497663691/Text_File_01-880f5.txt"
val readFileRDD = spark.sparkContext.textFile(dfsFilename)

// res4: Array[String] = Array(The the is Is a A to To OK ok I) //stopWords
val stopWordsInput = spark.sparkContext.textFile("/FileStore/tables/filter_words.txt")
val stopWords = stopWordsInput.flatMap(x => x.split(" ")).map(_.trim).collect.toSet
val broadcasted = sc.broadcast(stopWords)

val wcounts1 = readFileRDD.map(x => (x.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", " ")                                     
                      .trim.toLowerCase))
                      .flatMap(line=>line.split(" "))
                      .filter(broadcasted.value.contains(_))
                      .map(word=>(word, 1))
                      .reduceByKey(_ + _)

wcounts1.collect
```

returns:

```
res2: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((The,1), (I,3), (to,1), (the,1))
```

You can embellish with broadcast on the stopWords -which is what I did.

I saw you XML input and a replaceAll. You can fiddle with that to your liking. I also added a clause to put it all to lower case.